# Is there a way to create a background gradient in text component?

Tags: react-native, styles, underline

I'm trying to create a stylized underline like this one:

[image]

In this case i used this css in `h1`:

`background-image: linear-gradient(to top,rgba(39,128,196,0.73) 1%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 50%);`

But now i'm trying to recreate this in react-native, but i don't see how can i do it. I tried to use `react-native-linear-gradient` but only works for containers and not text component.

Comment: You could use `TextMask` Component to complete your task

Comment: How exactly i will use TextMask to do it?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials about it